# How can we emulate a reference to an object attribute so that its use is as simple and transparent as possible, in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, reference

(*Note:* I don't think this is a duplicate of the many questions about references to references because I already know Python does *not* support them. I'm asking how we can emulate them to make their use as simple and seamless as possible.)

***Use case***:

Let's say **we have an object `M` that contains two matrices `U1` and `U2`, and we want to return a view `U` of their product.** This is handy because **the user can write `M.U @ v`** directly instead of the more cumbersome `M.U1 @ (M.U2 @ v)` and `M.U1 @ M.U2 @ v`, which are not exactly equivalent from the point of view of time complexity. `M.U @ v` will pick the best one automatically.

**Since we need to support the `@` operator, `M.U` must be a property which returns (with caching) an object which refers to `M.U1` and `M.U2`**.

**The object `M` modifies not only the objects referenced by `U1` and `U2`, but also the references themselves.** This means that the view needs to reference the references themselves and not just the referenced objects.

**Now suppose we want to create an analogous view of two other matrices `V1` and `V2` contained in the same object.**

*Thoughts:*

1. If the two views are cached, there's only a single instance of each view so we could update them every time `M.U1` and `M.U2` are modified.
2. We could implement 1. by defining *setters* for `U1`, `U2`, `V1`, and `V2`.
3. If the views can create modified views (e.g. `U.T` returns the transposed of `U`) then we can break the updating mechanism if we're not careful.
4. Real references to `U1`, `U2`, `V1`, and `V2` would be *simpler*, *faster*, and *safer*, so I think they're the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution works seamlessly enough when one wants to access attributes, methods, or dunder methods (e.g. `__rmul__`) through a reference:

```py
r = Ref(some_obj, 'some_attr')
M = r @ some_other_operand
```

It may not work at all when the reference is passed to a function:

```py
M2 = compute_something(r)
```

That's because I have no way to intercept the access to `r`. For instance `np.linalg.svd(r)` doesn't work, but `np.linalg.svd(r[...])` does because `[...]` lets us do the dereferencing. Luckily for me, pytorch supports `r.svd()`, which is very convenient and doesn't suffer from the same problem.

Let me know if you have a way to solve that problem.

---

**EDIT:** The problem above can be solved by modifying `__bases__` of `Ref` so that `issubclass` believes our ref is a subclass of the correct type. Unfortunately, in Python 3, `__bases__` can be written only during class creation. That's good enough if a ref keeps pointing to objects of the same type, but if that's not the case, we need to create another class each time the type changes, and we need to catch the modification right when it happens! That's impossible AFAICT.

**EDIT2:** One solution is to add or replace `__getattribute__` on the object containing the reference we're referencing.

**Anyway,** I'll never use the code presented in this answer of mine. It was just an interesting exercise. Functions are *first-class* in Python, as we always say, but, unfortunately, references are not. One might misuse them, but don't we also say *We're all adults here?*.

---

Since it's difficult to know what dunder methods to support beforehand, I provide the function `add_types` which lets one add support for new types. For instance:

```py
import torch as T             # I use `T` in honor of theano ;)
import numpy as np

add_types(T.Tensor, np.ndarray)
```

Here's my first attempt:

```py
# TODO: Can we make this more robust and general?

_to_ignore = "new getattr getattribute setattr init class".split()
_default_types = [list, int, float]

_to_ignore = ['__' + n + '__' for n in _to_ignore]
_supported_types = set()
_dunder_ops = set()
_dunder_rops = set()


def _deref_refs(*objs):
    # TODO: inline this for efficiency?
    return [getattr(o._h6odj9348dh098d__obj, o._h6odj9348dh098d__attr)
                if isinstance(o, Ref) else o
            for o in objs]


def _create_op(name):
    def op(self, *args):
        obj, *args = _deref_refs(self, *args)
        return getattr(obj, name)(*args)

    def rop(self, *args):
        obj, *args = _deref_refs(self, *args)
        # Little hack: we can't remove an (r-)op (e.g. __radd__) so, when the
        #   referenced obj doesn't have it, we emulate its absence by falling
        #   back on the non-r version (e.g. __radd__ -> __add__) instead.
        rop = getattr(obj, name, None)
        if rop is not None:
            return rop(*args)
        # Switch to the non-r version of the op (and swap the operands).
        op_name = name[:2] + name[3:]           # __rXXX__ -> __XXX__
        return getattr(args[0], op_name)(obj, *args[1:])

    return rop if name in _dunder_rops else op


class Ref:
    def __init__(self, obj, attr):
        # 1. use mangling to avoid name conflicts
        # 2. use super().__setattr__ to avoid an infinite recursion
        super().__setattr__('_h6odj9348dh098d__obj', obj)
        super().__setattr__('_h6odj9348dh098d__attr', attr)

    @property
    def __class__(self):
        """This is necessary for faking our type."""
        return _deref_refs(self)[0].__class__

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        return getattr(*_deref_refs(self), item)

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        return setattr(*_deref_refs(self), key, value)


def add_types(*dir_ables):
    """Extends Ref support to other types. It can be called at any time."""
    global _dunder_ops, _dunder_rops, _supported_types

    new_dir_ables = set(dir_ables) - _supported_types
    if not new_dir_ables:
        return
    _dops = [d for t in new_dir_ables for d in dir(t)
             if (d[:2] == '__' == d[-2:]) and callable(getattr(t, d))]
    _dops = set(_dops).difference(_to_ignore)
    _new_dops = _dops - _dunder_ops
    _dunder_ops.update(_new_dops)
    _new_drops = set(d for d in _new_dops
                     if d.startswith('__r') and d[:2] + d[3:] in _dunder_ops)
    _dunder_rops.update(_new_drops)
    for dop in _new_dops:
        setattr(Ref, dop, _create_op(dop))
    _supported_types.update(new_dir_ables)


# Let's start with some default types...
add_types(*_default_types)


def test():
    test_torch = True
    # test_torch = False

    # General --------------------------------------------------------->

    class A:
        pass

    class B:
        def __init__(self, s):
            self.s = s
            self.a = A()

    b = B('word1 word2')
    s_ref = Ref(b, 's')
    assert 's_ref' + s_ref == 's_ref' + b.s
    assert s_ref + 's_ref' == b.s + 's_ref'
    assert s_ref + s_ref == b.s + b.s
    assert len(s_ref*3 + 'sdf') == len(b.s*3 + 'sdf')

    assert s_ref.split() == b.s.split()
    assert s_ref + 'ok' == b.s + 'ok'
    assert len(s_ref) == len(b.s)
    a_ref = Ref(b, 'a')
    a_ref.g = 23                # uses our __setattr__
    assert a_ref.g is b.a.g

    # Torch specific -------------------------------------------------->

    if test_torch:
        import torch as T           # I know, I know...

        class C:
            def __init__(self):
                self.M = T.randn(100, 100, dtype=T.float64)

        c = C()
        M_ref = Ref(c, 'M')
        try:
            M_ref @ M_ref           # must fail because '@' is missing
            assert False
        except TypeError:
            pass

        add_types(T.Tensor)         # adds '@' (and other stuff)
        MM = M_ref @ M_ref
        assert MM.allclose(c.M @ c.M)
        M3 = c.M * M_ref.svd(compute_uv=False)[1]
        # Note that [...] works even for scalars, while [:] doesn't.
        # M_ref *= T.svd(M_ref[...], compute_uv=False)[1]     # [...] hack!
        M_ref *= M_ref.svd(compute_uv=False)[1]           # no hack needed
        assert M_ref.allclose(M3)

    # Numpy specific -------------------------------------------------->

    import numpy as np          # I know, I know...

    class C:
        def __init__(self):
            self.M = np.random.randn(100, 100)

    c = C()
    M_ref = Ref(c, 'M')
    try:
        M_ref @ M_ref                   # must fail because '@' is missing
        assert False or test_torch      # ...unless we already tested torch
    except TypeError:
        pass

    add_types(np.ndarray)           # adds '@' (and other stuff)
    MM = M_ref @ M_ref
    assert np.allclose(MM, c.M @ c.M)
    M3 = c.M * np.linalg.svd(c.M, compute_uv=False)[1]
    # Note that [...] works even for scalars, while [:] doesn't.
    M_ref *= np.linalg.svd(M_ref[...], compute_uv=False)[1]     # [...] hack!
    assert np.allclose(M_ref, M3)
```